# cakephp validate translated field

Tags: validation, cakephp, translation, field

I have a model ex. posts that acts as translate and I want to validate the title which is a translated field.
How is this possible. The below does not work.

```
'title' => array(
    'notempty' => array(
    'rule' => array('notempty'),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you translate your message in /Locale default.po

```
'title' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'your translated message',
    ),
));
```

whats the big deal?

Comment: I tried this to validate form with both description. i.e. property.description.eng and property.description.cym on same form. I did not work.It just works for first field property.description.eng, but does not work for property.description.cym.  Is there different validation rule for such situation.

Answer (score 1):

Change rule name to camelCase: notEmpty and add message

Comment: OK but noone has ever come accross sth like this? I mean validated translated fields is sth very common in cms. How do you implement such functionality in cake ? Should be sth common but I can't find any documentation on it. PLease help.!

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html